# Android Studio Subversion commit ignoring new files

Tags: svn, android-studio, commit

I've made some changes to an Android project and am ready to commit them (using subversion). However, the commit display only shows that changed files are to be committed. It's ignoring new files - at least that's how it looks.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The Commit dialog does not show files which haven't been added to Subversion. You can find those files and add them to the VCS in the Changes view (VCS | Show Changes View) under "Unversioned files".

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to Eclipse/STS, which adds them by default.